# Iframe not working on online server

Tags: html, iframe

My iframe works properly on localhost but does not work on online servers.
please help...

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="287" width="300" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://tools.forexpros.com/market_quotes.php?tab_1=1,2,3,5,7,9&tab_2=169,166,20,172,27,178&tab_3=8830,8849,8836,8862,8831,8988&tab_4=8880,8907,8900,8899,8886,8895&select_color=000000&default_color=0059B0"> 
</iframe><br />
<div style="width:300">
  <span style="font-size: 11px;color: #333333;text-decoration: none;">The Market Quotes Powered By Forexpros, the Forex, Futures, and <a href="http://www.forexpros.com/" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;color: #06529D; font-weight: bold;" class="underline_link">Stock Markets</a> Portal.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me guess, are you trying to access the internals of an iframe hosting an external web page?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it load?

Comment: you iframe works on online servers: http://jsfiddle.net/VLqUD/

Answer (score 0):

The provided IFrame code is working fine on my account.

Either there may be issue in server configuration, on which your account is created, OR most probably sending the IFrame request is being blocked somewhere in your code to be sent to the server.

Please click on 'Reload' tab in the error message where the IFrame is supposed to be load.